# HtmlAgilityPack - How to get the tag by Id?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a task to do. I need to retrieve the a `tag` or `href` of a specific `id` (the `id` is based from the user input).
Example I have a `html` like this

```
<manifest>

<item href="Text/Cover.xhtml" id="Cov" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/Back.xhtml" id="Back" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
  </manifest>
```

I already have this code. Please, help me. Thank you

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document2 = new 

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document2.Load(@"C:\try.html");
HtmlNode[] nodes = document2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//manifest").ToArray();

foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If I understand correctly then:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document2.Load(@"C:\try.html");

string tag = document2.GetElementbyId("yourid").Name;
string href = document2.GetElementbyId("yourid").GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work recursively? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following XPath to find `item` element by its `id` attribute value :

```
var id = "Back";
var query = $"//manifest/item[@id='{id}']";
HtmlNode node = document2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query);
string href = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Comment: Just in case you're not familiar with the (`$`) sign : [string-interpolation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: something like this? but how can i get the output of that code? am i doing it right? because it gives me error on run time. sorry for my dumb question
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                document2.Load(@"C:\try.html");
                var id = "Back";
                var query = $"//manifest/item[@id='{id}']";
                HtmlNode node = document2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query);
                MessageBox.Show(node.ToString());